# Access table columns dynamically

Tags: postgresql

i would like to create a function to get table columns dynamically, what I mean by that

In js, we access objects by their key: `object["keyName"]`. Which goes directly to the value I want.

Basically my use case is that I have a series of localizations on my database, separated by the slug `label_country` i.e: `label_en`, `label_es` etc.

How could I create a function to select for `label_{someString}` and return that column?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have different columns for different countries? Looks like a problem in your datamodel.

Comment: @FrankHeikens the project was already running for so long... i can't change it right now but indeed, that is a problem.

Comment: _"I have a series of localizations on my database, separated by the slug label_country"_ : can you please provide the table definition and a data sample to better understand how the data are currently stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole row as JSON and then extract the column by its name. Here is an illustration.

```sql
create or replace function col_by_name(colname text, arg_id integer)
returns text language sql stable as
$$
 select (to_json(t)) ->> ('label_'||colname) from the_table t where id = arg_id
$$;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dc5b3/1).